# How to build your own linux?

Tags: linux, kernel

I wanted to make linux distro just for fun. i was thinking on what i could base it of can you suggest some propositions and pri time/tools that will allow me to make it ?

Comment: Starting with gentoo (or at least understand the documentation) would IMHO be the simplest path.

Comment: [SUSE Studio Express](https://studioexpress.opensuse.org/)
[SUSE Studio](https://www.susestudio.com/)

Comment: @J.Cravens I converted your answer to a comment. If you can summarize or reproduce the contents of the links here, that would be a great answer, but a link alone isn't an answer for these sites since the link may break and so leave the answer useless. Please see [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Base it on something you know! You'll get much further that way.

And be sure to define what a distribution is to you before starting. Moving towards a fluffy goal isn't (necessarily) fun.

Comment: thanks for responding and helping!

Answer (score 1):

There's a whole project devoted to this [Linux From Scratch](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/)